# Access VBA Execute WHERE before LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run a query to JOIN two tables, but I need the WHERE clause to run first on the Customer table and then the JOIN operation should run after it but I cant figure out how to do this.  I have tried the two following options, but it is still not working. The first one runs but there are no records in the query result. The second one does not run and I get a "JOIN expression not supported." message. However, when I remove the "AND c.sales_group = "Investor Owned Util"" line it runs. I want all the records from the Customer table where sales_group = "Investor Owned Util" and then from that query I want to JOIN it with the Orders table and show all orders for each customer.  The reason that I need the WHERE clause to run first is that I want to show the customers that have not placed any orders as well as the customers that have placed orders.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT c.ship_to_party, c.ship_to_name, c.sales_group
FROM (SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Customer.sales_group = "Investor Owned Util") AS c
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
ON c.ship_to_party = o.order_ship_to_party
ORDER BY c.ship_to_name;

SELECT c.ship_to_party, c.ship_to_name, c.sales_group
FROM Customer AS c
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
ON c.ship_to_party = o.order_ship_to_party
AND c.sales_group = "Investor Owned Util"
ORDER BY c.ship_to_name;
```

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Do you get records when you run `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Customer.sales_group = "Investor Owned Util";`?

Comment: Where is the VBA indicated in title?

Answer (score 0):

Move the Customer.sales_group selection criteria into a WHERE clause instead of being part of your JOIN.  This preserves the set of customers you want to see (since the Customers table is on the left of the join).

```
SELECT c.ship_to_party, c.ship_to_name, c.sales_group
FROM Customer AS c
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
ON c.ship_to_party = o.order_ship_to_party
WHERE c.sales_group = "Investor Owned Util"
ORDER BY c.ship_to_name;
```

It's worth noting that this query should be functionally equivalent to your first query, albeit slightly cleaner.  If you're getting 0 results, per JNevill's comment, verify that

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE sales_group = "Investor Owned Util"
```

is actually returning results.

Lastly, be careful when doing LEFT/RIGHT JOIN's and including additional join criteria as per your second query.  I know the query won't run in your case but in other DBMS this query would be valid.  See examples 1.2 and 1.3 [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/47637/inner-and-left-outer-join-with-where-clause-vs-on-clause/) for the difference in how the query is evaluated.